# how to write a module function that overrides imported function in perl

Tags: perl, module, subroutine

I have a question: I want to write a method called "copy" for my module M. This function is a wrapper of the imported function File::Copy::copy. So I have to use File::Copy::copy and define my own copy. But it will have an error saying that copy is redefined. How to achieve my goal?

```
#M.pm
package M;
use File::Copy;

#... constructor and other methods

sub copy {
  my $self = shift;
  my $target = shift;
  File::Copy::copy($self->{'PATH'},$target);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a different name? `mycopy`? Perl doesn't care what name you use.

Comment: because certain requirement. have to use same name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use File::Copy qw( );  # Don't import anything.
```

Answer (score 8):

I can think of three approaches

1. The `Subroutine ... redefined at ...` message is just a warning, not an error. If you "know what they're doing", call `no warnings "redefine"` before your redefinition.
2. As ikegami suggests, don't import anything. Or don't import everything. You could get away with

   `use File::Copy qw(move);   # still import move, don't import copy`
3. Explicitly undefine the function before you redefine it. You'll have to do this at compile time, so this belongs in a `BEGIN` block:

   `BEGIN {
       undef &copy;
   }`

   `sub copy { ... # redefinition`

Answer (score 0):

By prefixing an identifier with ! in the export list you can un-export it.

In the example below `move` as well as `copy` is being called. `move` produces an error because it can't find the files specified. `copy` is replaced by our definition of `copy`. If you remove that line you will find that the call to `copy` will result in an undefined function.

```
% perl <<'EOF'
use File::Copy qw(!copy);

sub copy { print "Hello world!\n" };

move("a", "b") or print "$!\n";
copy("a", "b") or print "$!\n";
EOF
No such file or directory
Hello world!
```